# Editting an SWF file that has embedded fonts in Flash CS6

Tags: flash, fonts, adobe, flash-cs6, fla

I am trying to edit a UI SWF file for a video game (Fallout 4) that contains the fonts that the other UI files use in-game.  Basically, replacing the fonts with a modified .ttf file I edited in FontForge.

The font files cannot have their names changed in the .swf or be renamed as exported .ttf files, so the name doesn't really match the actual typeface I replaced it with.  Basically I am replacing the characters and spacing/kerning data without adjusting anything else, since the names need to stay the same so the other UI files (which I need to leave unmodified) can reference and use them.  I'll explain why this is relevant later.

I tried using JPEXS flash decompiler to edit the .swf fonts, but there are a lot of spacing and alignment issues when embedding fonts that way, and I can't get the spacing changes I make in fontforge to apply, so I have been told the other option is to use Flash or Animate to edit the .swf file instead.

Using JPEXS to decompile this .swf and export it as a .fla file, I'm able to edit it in Flash CS6 (which is what I have access to).

The problem I am facing is that upon opening the .fla file in flash, I am met with a window that says the fonts are not found on my system, and to find something to substitute them with.  There is no way to browse to the individual .ttf files, and I can't just install those .ttf files in windows since they are modified versions of other fonts that would be replaced system wide.  Also, I will be working with multiple versions of this with differently modified fonts in different ways, that all have the same file name.  I will need to edit these .fla files side by side as well.

What I am asking is, how to you edit an SWF file that has embedded fonts in flash, or how can I convert the SWF file into a flash file that has the fonts embedded, rather than referencing the fonts I have installed in windows.

Comment: I don't think there's an official way to do it - if these assets were in SWF file with no clear way to edit - most likely it's by design. There are some tools that allow you to export assets from SWF files (swfrip is one of them), but again remember that SWF files are not meant to be decompiled - you probably would breach some T&C's trying to extract assets from there.

Comment: I am able to extract and import these assets within JPEXS, the issue is with the end result not aligning properly.  I have been told that it is possible to avoid this issue using flash, but if there is no way to embed font files in flash I'm not sure how